# Python Flask App Error in Running Sqlite 3

Tags: python, flask

I tried to make an app that shows data that was taken from the database. But then this error shows up when try to run the app "Could not build url for endpoint 'data'. Did you mean 'static' instead?"

I have tried to change the nav bar but it still have the same error while the theater link does not have that error.

This is the code that I tried:

**App.py**

```py
import sqlite3

###----------------Connecting to the database-------------#####
DB = sqlite3.connect("Slippingdata.db")

CURSOR = DB.cursor()
###----------------create the SQL command to create the table and save data-------------######
COMMAND1 = """ CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS
               USERS (
               User_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
               Name TEXT, 
               Username TEXT,
               Password TEXT,
               DOB DATE)"""

CURSOR.execute(COMMAND1)

COMMAND2 = """ CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS
                Sleepingreport (
                data_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
                Date DATE, 
                sleepingStart TIME,
                SleppingEnd TIME)"""

CURSOR.execute(COMMAND2)

from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/data', methods=["POST", "GET"])
def create():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('data.html')

    if request.method == 'POST':
        global Date, sleepingStart, SleppingEnd
        Date = request.form["DATEINPUT"]
        sleepingStart = request.form["SLIPPINGSTARTINPUT"]
        SleppingEnd = request.form["SLIPPINGENDINPUT"]

        # connect to db and insert data into the table
        connection = sqlite3.connect("Slippingdata.db")
        CURSOR = connection.cursor()
        CURSOR.execute("INSERT INTO USERS VALUES (NULL,?, ?, ?)", (Date, sleepingStart, SleppingEnd))
        connection.commit()
        connection.close()

        # extract the value and put in variable NAME
        return render_template("register.html")

    return redirect('url_for("report")')


app.run(debug=True)
```

**data.html**

```
 `    <html>
        <head>

        </head>
             <body>
                {% extends 'base.html' %}

                {% block body %}  

                <form name="REGISTERFORM" action="#" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                     <label for="DATE"></label>
                     <input type = "date" id="DATE" name="DATEINPUT" placeholder="DATE" required>
 
                     <br><br> 
    
                     <label for="SST"></label>
                     <input type = "time" id="SST" name="SLIPPINGSTARTINPUT" placeholder="SLEEPING START" required>
 
                     <br><br> 

                     <label for="SET"> </label>
                     <input type = "time" id="SET" name="SLIPPINGENDINPUT" placeholder="SLEPPING END"required>
  
                     <br><br>
                  </form>
    


                  {% endblock %}

              </body>

      </html>`
```

**nav.html**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html> 
     <head> 
       <title>Home</title> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='style.css') }}"> 
     </head>
          <body>
                <div class="nav">
                  <ul>
                       <li><a href="{{url_for ('index')}}"><img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='logo.png') }}" width="60px" hright="60px"></a></li>
                      <li><a href="{{url_for ('data')}}">Data</a></li>
                      <li><a href="{{url_for ('report')}}">Report</a></li>
                  </ul>
               </div>
           </body>

      </html>`
```

Comment: Your problem is totally unrelated to sqlite3, so your title is misleading.  This kind of thing usually means you made a change to the code and didn't restart the server.  Also, I don't see a handler for "report" here.